# Load an image into a PictureBox on a different thread

Tags: winforms, multithreading, image, c#-3.0, picturebox

I am trying to load a picture that is fetched on-demand from Google's Static Maps based against a (UK) Post Code.

Lets say I have a client and the clients has an address. One of the properties of client is PostCode. I have a form that loads clients. I feed the client ID to this form's constructor and then use LINQ 2 SQL to load all sorts of information including an address.

```
private void LoadBranchDetails() {
  Text_Update_BI_Name.Text = Branch.BranchNumber;
  Text_Update_BI_Manager.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", Branch.PharmacyManager.FirstName, Branch.PharmacyManager.LastName);
  DropDownList_Update_BI_Coordinator.SelectedValue = Branch.CoordinatorID;
  DropDownList_Update_BI_ComputerSystem.SelectedValue = Branch.ComputerSystemID;
  Text_Update_BI_Phone.Text = Branch.PhoneNumber;
  Text_Update_BI_Fax.Text = Branch.FaxNumber;

  Address BranchAddress = Branch.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
  Text_Update_AI_House.Text = BranchAddress.HouseNumber;
  Text_Update_AI_Street.Text = BranchAddress.Street;
  Text_Update_AI_Area.Text = BranchAddress.Area;
  Text_Update_AI_Post.Text = BranchAddress.PostCode;
  DropDownList_Update_AI_City.SelectedValue = BranchAddress.City.OID;

  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoPharmacist.Value = Branch.NumberOfPharmacists;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoDispensers.Value = Branch.NumberOfDispensers;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoMonFri.Value = Branch.NumberOfItemsMondayToFriday;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoSat.Value = Branch.NumberOfItemsSaturday;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoSun.Value = Branch.NumberOfItemsSunday;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoAddicts.Value = Branch.NumberOfAddicts;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoSupervised.Value = Branch.Supervised;
  MaskedText_Update_OI_NoUnsupervised.Value = Branch.Unsupervised;

  Check_Update_OI_ConfRoom.Checked = Branch.ConsultationRoom;

  try {        
    PictureGoogleMaps.Image = GoogleAddressInfo.FetchMapInfo(Text_Update_AI_Post.Text).GoogleStaticMap;

  } catch (Exception) {
    PictureGoogleMaps.Image = Resources.DefaultGoogleMap;

  }
}
```

The line that loads the image into the PictureGoogleMaps causes a hang in UI as the ".GoogleStaticMap" property generates the Google static image when called.

Upon searching the internet, i found this helpful example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Declare a list of URLs and their respective picture boxes
        var items = new Dictionary<string, PictureBox> 
        { 
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/spring09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 0, Width = 300, Height = 80  } }, 
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/stpatricks_d4gwinner_eo09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 100, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/schiaparelli09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 200, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/drseuss09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 300, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/valentines09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 400, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/unix1234567890.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 500, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
            { "http://www.google.com/logos/charlesdarwin_09.gif", new PictureBox() { Top = 600, Width = 300, Height = 80 } },
        };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (o, e) =>
            {
                // This function will be run on a background thread
                // spawned from the thread pool.
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var pair = (KeyValuePair<string, PictureBox>)e.Argument;
                    e.Result = new KeyValuePair<PictureBox, byte[]>(pair.Value, client.DownloadData(pair.Key));
                }
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => 
            {
                // This function will be run on the main GUI thread
                var pair = (KeyValuePair<PictureBox, byte[]>)e.Result;
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(pair.Value))
                {
                    pair.Key.Image = new Bitmap(stream);
                }
                Controls.Add(pair.Key);
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I just need to figure out how to remove the for loop and use this in my scenario. Any ideas?

The sample code comes from this [link](http://bit.ly/fjiVBB).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        private BackgroundWorker imageLoader;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.imageLoader = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.imageLoader.DoWork += HandleOnImageLoaderDoWork;
            this.imageLoader.RunWorkerCompleted += HandleImageLoaderOnRunWorkerCompleted;

            this.LoadUserDetails(1);
        }

        private void LoadUserDetails(Int32 userID)
        {
            this.imageLoader.RunWorkerAsync(userID.ToString());
            // get the user details
            // populate the UI controls with the data....
        }

        private void HandleImageLoaderOnRunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Result;
        }

        private void HandleOnImageLoaderDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // simulate a web request for an image;
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Image image = Image.FromFile(@"test.jpg");
            e.Result = image;
        }
    }
```

Also make sure that you show some UI notification that a background operation is in process...something like a initial image (loading.gif) in the PictureBox.

Comment: Thanks. This will work nicely. Also, I noticed that you sent a user id to the RunWorkerAsync like: this.imageLoader.RunWorkerAsync(userID.ToString()); Now I wonder if I can use this approach to load the data itself along with the image.

Comment: Yes, you can. But to keep code clean, you can create a type (which holds data) and pass it between DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Is it that hard to remove the foreach loop? You only need to load a single picture so remove the foreach loop and pass the url of the picture and the target picturebox to the backgroundworker.

Comment: No, removing the ForEach was easy. I was a bit confused at the last line of the loop:  worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);